# Maven Jacoco Code Coverage Report with failed Unit Tests, ignore failed tests

Tags: maven, unit-testing, testing, jacoco

I am currently evaluating an AI-based tool for generating unit tests by tracking code coverage and successful test runs with Maven. However, if a unit test fails, no coverage report is generated.

I've tried several commands like

`mvn clean verify -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`

or

`mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true surefire-report:report`

but nothing seems to help to solve my problem. I don't want to manually fix or remove the failed tests, as doing so would manipulate my evaluation results.

pom.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dailycodebuffer</groupId>
    <artifactId>JaCoCo-Demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JaCoCo-Demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>run-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post the full pom file...

Comment: Sorry, added the pom.xml

Comment: Why is maven-surefire-plugin in a profile? Remove the profile... also use a more recent version of spring boot because that version is end of support for a long time (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) also JaCoCo version is out of date...Which version of Maven do you use? Also use `mvn --fail-at-end ...`?

Comment: PS D:\JaCoCo-Demo> mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.6 
Java version: 21.0.2